# How to efficiently read files with path in spark, i.e. want `wholeTextFiles` that returns `RDD[String, Iterator[String]]`

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, bigdata

A common problem in Big Data is getting data into Big Data friendly format (parquet or TSV).

In Spark `wholeTextFiles` which currently returns `RDD[(String, String)]` (path -> whole file as string) is a useful method for this but causes many issues when the files are large (mainly memory issues).

In principle it ought to be possible to write a method as follows using the underlying Hadoop API

```
def wholeTextFilesIterators(path: String): RDD[(String, Iterator[String])]
```

Where the iterator is the file (assuming newline as delimiter) and the iterator is encapsulating the underlying file reading & buffering.

After reading through the code for a while I think a solution would involve creating something similar to `WholeTextFileInputFormat` and `WholeTextFileRecordReader`.

UPDATE:

After some thought this probably means also implementing a custom `org.apache.hadoop.io.BinaryComparable` so the iterator can survive a shuffle (hard to serialise the iterator as it has file handle).

See also https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-22225

[Spark-Obtaining file name in RDDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29686573/spark-obtaining-file-name-in-rdds)

Comment: Why not use Hadoop's plain `TextInputFormat`? It gives you row sharding and streaming out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

As per Hyukjin's comment on the JIRA, something close to what is wanted is given by

```
spark.format("text").read("...").selectExpr("value", "input_file_name()")
```