# spark whole textiles - many small files

Tags: scala, apache-spark, optimization, geotools

I want to ingest many small text files via spark to parquet. Currently, I use `wholeTextFiles` and perform some parsing additionally.

To be more precise - these small text files are ESRi ASCII Grid files each with a maximum size of around 400kb. GeoTools are used to parse them as outlined below.

Do you see any optimization possibilities? Maybe something to avoid the creation of unnecessary objects? Or something to better handle the small files. I wonder if it is better to only get the paths of the files and manually read them instead of using `String -> ByteArrayInputStream`.

```
case class RawRecords(path: String, content: String)
case class GeometryId(idPath: String, value: Double, geo: String)
@transient lazy val extractor = new PolygonExtractionProcess()
@transient lazy val writer = new WKTWriter()

def readRawFiles(path: String, parallelism: Int, spark: SparkSession) = {
    import spark.implicits._
    spark.sparkContext
      .wholeTextFiles(path, parallelism)
      .toDF("path", "content")
      .as[RawRecords]
      .mapPartitions(mapToSimpleTypes)
  }

def mapToSimpleTypes(iterator: Iterator[RawRecords]): Iterator[GeometryId] = iterator.flatMap(r => {
    val extractor = new PolygonExtractionProcess()

    // http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/coverage/arcgrid.html
    val readRaster = new ArcGridReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(r.content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))).read(null)

    // TODO maybe consider optimization of known size instead of using growable data structure
    val vectorizedFeatures = extractor.execute(readRaster, 0, true, null, null, null, null).features
    val result: collection.Seq[GeometryId] with Growable[GeometryId] = mutable.Buffer[GeometryId]()

    while (vectorizedFeatures.hasNext) {
      val vectorizedFeature = vectorizedFeatures.next()
      val geomWKTLineString = vectorizedFeature.getDefaultGeometry match {
        case g: Geometry => writer.write(g)
      }
      val geomUserdata = vectorizedFeature.getAttribute(1).asInstanceOf[Double]
      result += GeometryId(r.path, geomUserdata, geomWKTLineString)
    }
    result
  })
```

Comment: Please see my answer here if it helps, but again thats with dataframe: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45227410/297113

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have suggestions:

1. use `wholeTextFile` -> `mapPartitions` -> convert to Dataset. Why? If you make `mapPartitions` on Dataset, then all rows are converted from internal format to object - it causes additional serialization.
2. Run Java Mission Control and sample your application. It will show all compilations and times of execution of methods
3. Maybe you can use `binaryFiles`, it will give you `Stream`, so you can parse it without additional reading in `mapPartitions`

Comment: Shouldn't tungstens compression make up for all the object problems? Is there something like `wholeBinaryFiles` which will give me the path and the whole file?

Comment: @GeorgHeiler You can use `SparkContext.binaryFiles`, it returns pair FilePath, DataStream

Comment: What type of stream is the `PortableDataStream`? When using ` new ArcGridReader(r._2).read(null)` I get an `ERROR arcgrid: Unsupported input type `. Any regular input stream should be supported by https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/plugin/arcgrid/src/main/java/org/geotools/gce/arcgrid/ArcGridReader.java#L119

Comment: Edit: it works fine, I was missing a call to `open` on the `PortableDataStream `. I will do some profiling now.

Comment: I ultimately want to have a data frame to dump to parquet. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29686573/spark-obtaining-file-name-in-rdds/36356253#36356253 is using `spark.read.text`. Do you think using this instead would be better? But that again would result in many `String` objects.