# How to apply a repartition using a window in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark

I have a column `Foo` which contains `double` value such as:

```
[ 100.4, 39.6, 98.2, 10.8, 62.1, 69.6 … ]
```

I would like to repartition using a window of `10` which would generate a dataset something like:

```
Foo=10
Foo=20
Foo=30
Foo=40
Foo=50
Foo=60
Foo=70
Foo=80
Foo=90
Foo=100
Foo=110
```

The use of `repartiton(number: int, colname: str)` split the dataframe to the given `number` of files. But I can not choose the window.

So how to do it in pyspark ?

thanks

Comment: u want to write to different files based on window? like use window to put column into repartition function before writing?

Comment: yes, I would like to write to different files based on window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you do mean by repartitioning, but in any case, assuming you have a `df` of:

```
+-----+
|  Foo|
+-----+
|100.4|
| 39.6|
| 98.2|
| 10.8|
| 62.1|
| 69.6|
+-----+
```

You can easily round your values:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, floor
df2 = df.withColumn('Foo_binned', floor(col('Foo') / 10) * 10)
```

```
+-----+----------+
|  Foo|Foo_binned|
+-----+----------+
|100.4|       100|
| 39.6|        30|
| 98.2|        90|
| 10.8|        10|
| 62.1|        60|
| 69.6|        60|
+-----+----------+
```

If this is a result you are looking for, you can select / rename just the new column. You can also just change the method for rounding dependently on your requirements (`floor`, `round`, `ceil`).

If by repartitioning you actually want to physically save the values in different folders based on the bucketing into 10's, you can run:

```
df2.write.partitionBy('Foo_binned').csv('./foos.csv')
```

Which will partition the data while saving:

```
30.03.2020  23:05                 8 ._SUCCESS.crc
30.03.2020  23:05    <DIR>          Foo_binned=10
30.03.2020  23:05    <DIR>          Foo_binned=100
30.03.2020  23:05    <DIR>          Foo_binned=30
30.03.2020  23:05    <DIR>          Foo_binned=60
30.03.2020  23:05    <DIR>          Foo_binned=90
30.03.2020  23:05                 0 _SUCCESS
```

Last but not least, if you just want your in-memory data partitioned by those buckets, it's pretty hard to achieve, because, well, you shouldn't be doing that. Spark includes an optimization engine that will do it's best when you just let it

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([ (100.2,), (100.1,), (100.7,), (100.4,), (39.6, ), (39.6, ), (39.6, ), (39.6, ), (98.2, ), (10.8, ), (10.2, ), (10.8, ), (10.8, ), (62.1, ), (69.6, )], ['Foo'])
df2 = df.repartitionByRange('Foo')
print('No of partitions', df2.rdd.getNumPartitions())
```

`No of partitions 8`

Comment: thanks daniel, I used the word `repartion` as to me it was used to achieve the goal: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44808415/spark-parquet-partitioning-large-number-of-files

Answer (score 1):

Adding to **Daniel's** answer.

```
+-----+----------+
|  Foo|Foo_binned|
+-----+----------+
|100.4|       100|
| 39.6|        30|
| 98.2|        90|
| 10.8|        10|
| 62.1|        60|
| 69.6|        60|
+-----+----------+
```

This will ensure that for **every** foo range, you get **1 file.**

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
n = df.select(F.col('Foo_binned')).distinct().count()

data.repartition(n)\
     .write \
     .partitionBy("Foo_binned")\
     .csv(path)
```