# pyspark writing lot of smaller files in output

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark, amazon-athena

I'm using pyspark to process some data and write the output to S3. I have created a table in athena which will be used to query this data.

Data is in the form of json strings (one per line) and spark code reads the file, partition it based on certain fields and write to S3.

For a 1.1 GB file, I see that spark is writing 36 files with 5 MB approx per file size. when reading athena documentation I see that optimal file size is ~128 MB . https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/top-10-performance-tuning-tips-for-amazon-athena/

```
sparkSess = SparkSession.builder\
    .appName("testApp")\
    .config("spark.debug.maxToStringFields", "1000")\
    .config("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode", "dynamic")\
    .getOrCreate()

sparkCtx = sparkSess.sparkContext
deltaRdd = sparkCtx.textFile(filePath)
df = sparkSess.createDataFrame(deltaRdd, schema)

try:
    df.write.partitionBy('field1','field2','field3')\
        .json(path, mode='overwrite', compression=compression)
except Exception as e:
    print (e)
```

why spark is writing such smaller files. Is there any way to control file size.

Comment: Can you post your pyspark code along with source for your pyspark job?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you control the size of the output file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187622/how-do-you-control-the-size-of-the-output-file)

Comment: No, it doesn't. There are mixed answer to this question. some says using fs.s3a.multipart.size /fs.s3a.block.size property this size can be controlled but it does not work or I'm missing something. some answer says this can not be controlled like the one posted above . its confusing .

Comment: @Kapil did you ever resolve this issue? What was your solution at the end? I am experiencing exactly the same behavior

Comment: @cool It was more of a work around. I repartitioned the data and limiting the file size. I know the average record size. based on that, I'm setting the maxRecordsPerFile to keep the file size growing infinitely.

Comment: @Kapil Thank you for following on that. So, repartitioning data and maxRecordsPerFile from the pyspark app (python code) was enough to achieve this. You did not have to deal with fs multipart size configurations?

Comment: @cool Yes. that was enough to limit the no of files. Now a new file is only created if no of records are more than specified. I have created a gist with that code . see if it helps https://gist.github.com/kapilgarg/ed605408aee21166ba6394a483e1f260

Comment: @Kapil thanks again, this will help. Maybe it would be good for you to elaborate this discussion in an answer by yourself and mark it as accepted, just for the sake of resolution.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to control file size?

There are some control mechanism. However they are not explicit.

The s3 drivers are not part of spark itself. They are part of the hadoop installation which ships with spark emr.  The s3 block size can be set within 
`/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml` [config file](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html#General_S3A_Client_configuration).

However by default it should be around 128 mb.

> why spark is writing such smaller files

Spark will adhere to the hadoop block size. However you can use `partionBy` before writing.

Lets say you use `partionBy("date").write.csv("s3://products/")`. 
Spark will create a subfolder with the `date` for each partition. Within
each partioned folder spark will again try to create chunks and try to adhere to the `fs.s3a.block.size`.

e.g

```
s3:/products/date=20191127/00000.csv
s3:/products/date=20191127/00001.csv
s3:/products/date=20200101/00000.csv
```

In the example above - a particular partition can just be smaller than a blocksize of 128mb.

So just double check your block size in `/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml` and wether you need to partition the data frame with `partitionBy` before writing.

**Edit:**

[Similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44459355/spark-dataframe-write-method-writing-many-small-files) also suggests to repartition the dataframe to match the `partitionBy` scheme

```
df.repartition('field1','field2','field3')
.write.partitionBy('field1','field2','field3')
```

`writer.partitionBy` operates on the existing dataframe partitions. It will not `repartition` the original dataframe. Hence if the overall dataframe is paritioned differently, there is nested partitioning happening.

Comment: even though, complete data corresponds to a single partition, file size is still not 128. I don't have any entry in core-site.xml so assuming it is taking default size but after updating the property for multipart upload , no change

Comment: did you check the hadoop s3 conf? what is the s3 block.size?

Comment: when i  check spark-emr hadoop conf, there is no setting for s3 block.size at all. the files we write come out around 150 mb.  Do a `cd /etc/hadoop/conf/` then run `grep -rni "s3" *` to check wether there is `block.size` setting

Comment: Just also saw, we repartition the dataframe to match the datawriter schema. added another hint to the answer